# Memory issues when using malloc-allocated data with OpenGL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

I allocate some data, C-style, like this (some initialization code left out):

```
room_t* make_room(int width, int height)
{
    room_t* room = (room_t*) malloc(sizeof(room_t));

    /* Initialization code sets some stuff, no allocations */

    return room;
}
```

After that I use this function in a Cocoa view inheriting from `NSOpenGLView` like this:

```
- (void) drawRect: (NSRect) bounds
{
    room_t* room = make_room(4, 4);

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    draw_room(room, 0);

    destroy_room(room);
}
```

`draw_room` is a simple function that draws a few triangles and `destroy_room` deallocates the object.  However, I get an error on glClear (`SIGABRT`) like this:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x101811bf8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
```

So, to me, it seems like the OpenGL functions are trying to free something but I'm not sure.  Either way, if I stop using my `malloc`'d object and instead just draw the triangles hard-coded everything works fine.

I should also say that just allocating the `room_t` data will make the program crash, I don't have to use any data from the allocated object in order to get the crash.  Am I not allowed to use `malloc` in Cocoa code like this or is it something else I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, to me, it seems like the OpenGL functions are trying to free something

OpenGL will never free any memory pointed to by a client supplied pointer.

> malloc: *** error for object 0x101811bf8: incorrect checksum for freed object

This sounds to me, that you somewhere have a out-of-bounds write that kills the canary value.

Comment: Sometimes you just need someone to point out that you're an idiot.  Apparently I suck at pointer arithmetic.  I guess I started blaming Cocoa because the crash appeared at the "wrong" place.  Thanks, and sorry for wasting your time!